# Unnecessary premises in proposition about base change (Görtz-Wedhorn)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Here is proposition 4.20 from Görtz and Wedhorn's *Algebraic Geometry I*.
[image]

It seems to me that the right square in (4.5.1) is completely unnecessary: We can always choose $S = X$ making the right square trivial (and replacing $X \times_S Y$ by just $Y$). This however doesn't loose any generality since we just relax the assumptions: instead of needing two Cartesian squares of schemes, we now only need one.

The right square also isn't mentioned in the results of the theorem.

Am I right? And if so what is the reason why the authors included the right square in the statement of the theorem?

Comment: Replacing $S$ by $X$ assumes that $Y$ is a scheme over $X$, which need not be the case.

Comment: @red_trumpet that's not what I mean. You can look at the special case where $S = X$ and $Y$ is an $X$-Scheme, in which you don't need the right square. The general case then follows from setting $Y = Y \times_S X$ (which is an $X$-Scheme).